# Limit page depth on scrapy crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I have a scraper that takes in a list of URLS, and scans them for additional links, that it then follows to find anything that looks like an email (using REGEX), and returns a list of urls/email addresses.

I currently have it set up in a Jupyter Notebook, so I can easily view the output while testing. The problem is, it takes forever to run - because I'm not limiting the depth of the scraper (per URL).

Ideally, the scraper would go a max of 2-5 pages deep from each start url.

Here's what I have so far:

First, I'm importing my dependencies:

```
import os, re, csv, scrapy, logging
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from googlesearch import search
from time import sleep
from Urls import URL_List
```

And I set turn off logs and warnings for using Scrapy inside the Jupyter Notebook:

```
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False
```

From there, I extract the URLS from my URL file:

```
def get_urls():
    urls = URL_List['urls']
```

Then, I set up my spider:

```
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'email'
    def parse(self, response):
```

I search for links inside URLs.

```
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
```

Then take in a list of URLs as input, reading their source codes one by one.

```
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))
```

I send links from one parse method to another. 
And set callback argument that defines which method the request URL must be sent to.

```
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link)
```

I then pass URLS to the parse_link method — this method applies regex findall to look for emails

```
    def parse_link(self, response):
        html_text = str(response.text)
        mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)
        dic = {'email': mail_list, 'link': str(response.url)}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
```

The google_urls list are passed as an argument when we call the process method to run the Spider, path defines where to save the CSV file.

Then, I save those emails in a CSV file:

```
def ask_user(question):
    response = input(question + ' y/n' + '\n')
    if response == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def create_file(path):
    response = False
    if os.path.exists(path):
        response = ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
        if response == False: return 
    with open(path, 'wb') as file: 
        file.close()
```

For each website, I make a data frame with columns: [email, link], and append it to a previously created CSV file.

Then, I put it all together:

```
def get_info(root_file, path):  
    create_file(path)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['email', 'link'], index=[0])
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    print('Collecting urls...')
    google_urls = get_urls()

    print('Searching for emails...')
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    process.crawl(MailSpider, start_urls=google_urls, path=path)

    process.start()

    print('Cleaning emails...')
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
    df.columns = ['email', 'link']
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='email')
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    return df

get_urls()
```

Lastly, I define a keyword and run the scraper:

```
keyword = input("Who is the client? ")
df = get_info(f'{keyword}_urls.py', f'{keyword}_emails.csv')
```

On a list of 100 URLS, I got back 44k results with an email addresses syntax.

Anyone know how to limit the depth?

Comment: You can set a depth limit using the DepthLimitMiddleware which is enabled by default. For its settings see: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.depth

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Do you know how to run it inside the file @PhungDuyPhong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set DEPTH_LIMIT in your Spider like this

```
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'email'

    custom_settings = {
        "DEPTH_LIMIT": 5
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```